# Convert rarefaction plots from Vegan to ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

Hi I am running species estimator calculations in the package 'vegan'.

The code I'm running is very simple:

```
library(vegan)    
data(BCI)
p<-poolaccum(BCI, permutations = 50)
p.plot<-plot(p, display = c("chao", "jack1", "jack2"))
```

The object `p.plot` is a trellis type object. So I was not able to convert it to a dataframe to for ggplot. The reason why I want to be able to use ggplot is because I want all the estimator curves to be on the same graph with labels. I'm also doing these plots for other datasets and I want to consolidate space as much as possible.

Any help would be great! Thank you

Comment: Maybe this https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`summary(p)` can help you get input data for ggplot2. I demonstrate Chao plot here:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
chao <- data.frame(summary(p)$chao,check.names = FALSE)
colnames(chao) <- c("N", "Chao", "lower2.5", "higher97.5", "std")
chao_melt <- melt(chao, id.vars = c("N","std"))
ggplot(data = chao_melt, aes(x = N, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = variable))
```

`p` is what you got in `p<-poolaccum(BCI, permutations = 50)` The output is like this, you can make some adjustment for multiple plots and theme.
[image]

Comment: thank you @Xi wa ,  I have a  question about the permutations argument in the poolaccum() I'm assuming that the argument is giving the option for the number of random re-orderings for calculating the estimators?

Comment: @Leo Ohyama It seems that the function is used to estimate richness according to the samples you provided. It starts with the minimal amount(minisize default is 3) of samples to estimate richness, then 4,5,6...50. Permutations is used to repeat n times to give confidence interval. For example at the size of 3 samples, repeat estimating richness n times, got the estimated value and its confidence interval.